# Question about mac app store

Tags: macos, app-store

If i submit a mac application to the mac app store, am i allowed to submit it to Bodega and other stores as well?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. Just make sure you remove the receipt validation code for the non-App Store versions.

Comment: Accepted answer and thumbed up!